# I want to swap text TextFields

Tags: java, awt, gettext, settext

I tried to swap text of TextField But Only one TextField was changed other one stayed same :/,

My code is

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

        class mywindowclosing extends WindowAdapter {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                        System.exit(0);
                }       
        }
        class Toggle extends Frame implements ActionListener {
                Label lb1, lb2;
                TextField txt1, txt2;
                Button bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4,bt5;
                public Toggle(){
                    super(".::Assignment::.");
                    setBounds(200,200,400,210);
                    setBackground(new Color(75,0,130));
                    setVisible(true);
                    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                    //First Row
                    lb1=new Label("Label 1 ");
                    add(lb1);
                    txt1=new TextField(30);
                    add(txt1);
                    bt1=new Button("Button 1");
                    add(bt1);
                    bt1.addActionListener(this);
                    //2nd Row
                    lb2=new Label("Label 2 ");
                    add(lb2);
                    txt2=new TextField(30);
                    add(txt2);
                    bt2=new Button("Button 2");
                    add(bt2);
                    bt2.addActionListener(this);
                    //3rd Row
                    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
                    bt3=new Button("Clear");
                    add(bt3);
                    bt3.addActionListener(this);
                    bt4=new Button("Toggle");
                    add(bt4);
                    bt4.addActionListener(this);
                    bt5=new Button("Exit");
                    add(bt5);
                    bt5.addActionListener(this);
                    addWindowListener(new mywindowclosing());
                }

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        if(ae.getSource()==bt1) {
                        txt1.setText("Button 1 pressed");
                        }
                        if(ae.getSource()==bt2) {
                        txt2.setText("Button 2 pressed");
                        }
                        if(ae.getSource()==bt3) {
                        txt1.setText("");
                        txt2.setText("");
                        }
                        if(ae.getSource()==bt4) {
                        txt1.setText(txt2.getText());
                        txt2.setText(txt1.getText());
                        }
                        if(ae.getSource()==bt5) {
                        System.exit(0);
                        }
                }       
        }       
        public class Toggler {
            public static void main(String args[]) {
                new Toggle();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code below:

```
  if(ae.getSource()==bt4) {
                txt1.setText(txt2.getText());
                txt2.setText(txt1.getText());
                }
```

**After doing this, the text in txt1 (TextField ) and txt2 (TextField ) will be the same.**

If you would like to swap the text between them, you need to use a temporary variable.

Have a try with this:

```
    if (ae.getSource() == bt4) {

        String saveText1 = txt1.getText();
        txt1.setText(txt2.getText());
        txt2.setText(saveText1);
    }
```

Comment: Tsk, tsk, you ruined my guessing game ;)

Comment: I am a beginner .. i don't know much :/ , Thanks again for your Help..!

Answer (score 2):

```
txt1.setText(txt2.getText());
txt2.setText(txt1.getText());
```

Ask yourself - what is the value of txt1 after you do the first line? And, consequently, what gets written to txt2?

[Hint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: When I press toggle button TextField txt1 changes but TextField txt2 remains same .. :/ :(

Comment: Of course it does. Think about the following code: `int a = 0, b = 1; a = b; b = a;`. What values do you have when you *copy* `b` to `a`? Something is lost.

Comment: When I press Button 1 it shows in txt1 TextField that Button 1 pressed, same with when i press Button 2 it show in txt2 field that Button 2 is pressed,

Comment: I want that those two text fields change their text with one another when i press toggle button .. :/